# TensorFlow: DNNRegressor, how to save a model to predict from

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm new to TensorFlow and am trying to convert on of my scikit-learn models to TensorFlow notation, but I am finding it excessively complicated.

In scikit-learn you simply call `model.dump("ModelName.pkl")` to save the model and call `joblib.load("ModelName.pkl")` to use it again. I am trying to do a similar thing with TensorFlow, but I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user0/Desktop/IPML_Model/tensorflow_model_train.py", line 39, in <module>
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1139, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1161, in build
    raise ValueError("No variables to save")
ValueError: No variables to save
```

All I want to do is train the model with `get_training_data()`, save it, and then load it so I can call `predict`. Here is what I have:

```
def get_training_data():
    X, y = preprocess_data()

    X_train, _, y_train, _ = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=123)

    feature_set = {f: tf.constant(X_train[f]) for f in features}
    label_set = tf.constant(y_train)

    return feature_set, label_set

# Start a session
sess = tf.Session()

# Initialize a DNNRegressor model
feature_cols = [real_valued_column(k) for k in features]
dnn_regressor = DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_cols, hidden_units=[50, 50], label_dimension=7, model_dir=os.getcwd())

# Train the model
dnn_regressor.fit(input_fn=lambda: get_training_data(), steps=5000)

# Save the model
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(sess, "dnnregressor.ckpt")
```

I can call `predict` on `dnnregressor` after fitting and that requires no "Variables", but I want to first save the model *then* call predict. What is simplest, most minimal way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is saved in the `model_dir` when you were calling:

```
dnn_regressor = DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_cols, hidden_units=[50, 50], label_dimension=7, model_dir=os.getcwd())
```

Now during `inference` you call the above again, it will load the model from the `model_dir` and then call the `dnn_regressor.predict()` function.

Comment: What do you mean by inference you call the above again?